# kernel interrupt handler function type (compile error)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling, irq

I'm setting up a kernel interrupt handler with:

```
        irq_result = request_irq(53, gpeds_hdlr, 0, "gpeds_hdlr", NULL);
```

Then, I'm defining my interrupt handler with:

```
irq_handler_t gpeds_hdlr(int irq, void *dev_id)
```

Compiler complains with:

```
/home/pi/module/mod_gpio.c: In function ‘init_function’:
/home/pi/module/mod_gpio.c:86:31: error: passing argument 2 of ‘request_irq’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  irq_result = request_irq(53, gpeds_hdlr, 0, "gpeds_hdlr", NULL);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/module/mod_gpio.c:1:
./include/linux/interrupt.h:157:45: note: expected ‘irq_handler_t’ {aka ‘enum irqreturn (*)(int,  void *)’} but argument is of type ‘irqreturn_t (* (*)(int,  void *))(int,  void *)’ {aka ‘enum irqreturn (* (*)(int,  void *))(int,  void *)’}
 request_irq(unsigned int irq, irq_handler_t handler, unsigned long flags,
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

If I define my interrupt handler this way, as suggested by some online resources:

```
irqreturn_t gpeds_hdlr(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs) {
```

Then I get a very similar compile error:

```
/home/pi/module/mod_gpio.c: In function ‘init_function’:
/home/pi/module/mod_gpio.c:85:31: error: passing argument 2 of ‘request_irq’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  irq_result = request_irq(53, gpeds_hdlr, 0, "gpeds_hdlr", NULL);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/module/mod_gpio.c:1:
./include/linux/interrupt.h:157:45: note: expected ‘irq_handler_t’ {aka ‘enum irqreturn (*)(int,  void *)’} but argument is of type ‘irqreturn_t (*)(int,  void *, struct pt_regs *)’ {aka ‘enum irqreturn (*)(int,  void *, struct pt_regs *)’}
 request_irq(unsigned int irq, irq_handler_t handler, unsigned long flags,
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

How do I get past this?

Of note: `linux/interrupt.h` contains:

```
typedef irqreturn_t (*irq_handler_t)(int, void *);
```

and `linux/irqreturn.h`, included from `linux/interrupt.h`, contains:

```
typedef enum irqreturn irqreturn_t;
```

Thanks!

Comment: The third parameter of the handler (`struct pt_regs *regs`) was removed in kernel version 2.6.19 over 14 years ago.

Comment: Side note: 53 is not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes the number is off. (Orthogonal to the inquiry, but yes.)

Answer (score 3):

You should define your handler as following and pass handler to `request_irq()`.

```
irqreturn_t handler(int irq, void *data){ }
```

The second error of yours is because you are saying that handler receives 3 parameters while it's supposed to receive only two.

The first error is because that the definitions are wrong you say handler is returning `irq_handler_t` while it's supposed to return `irqreturn_t` which is a typedef for an enum. while `irq_handler_t` is typedef for a function pointer.

Comment: Thanks, I think the syntax of function pointer typedef threw me off some.

Comment: @Yaron Shragai: it's admittedly two years after you got this reply.  But please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" is.